# User input in a messageDialog box

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to add a custom user input field in a messageDialog box, like the one below in the Bing Sports app. However, it seems you can only add commands, which are buttons. Any help?

(I'm working in HTML/JavaScript)

Normally, control over messageDialog boxes appears as follows:

```
var dialogMessage = 'This is the dialog text';
var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog( dialogMessage );
dialog.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Button", function (command) {
    /* Action goes here */
}));
dialog.showAsync();
```

As you can see, you can only append a command to the dialogMessage, in the form of an actionable button...

[image]

Comment: oops, forgot to add that. Javascript

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused, could you please explain what you mean by "However, it seems you can only add commands, which are buttons"?

Comment: yes... what do you mean a command? are you trying to add a close function?

Comment: I mean that the only things you can use to define the messageDialog are two strings- one for the title, one for the content, and then you can add "commands," which are the actionable buttons (In the photo, the two commands are Add and Close). What I want is to be able to add the text input field next to the commands, for which there seems to be no option...

Answer (score 4):

I've been stuck with the same problem for a few days now, and after hours of searching I still haven't found anything that lets you add an input text field to your MessageDialog. Note that I am fairly new to Windows 8 development, though I do have a few years of JavaScript experience.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but since I wanted the input fields for a login, I came across [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfox/archive/2012/07/05/windows-8-leveraging-the-credentialpicker.aspx) from MSDN's blog. It explains the CredentialPicker class which is somewhat similar to the MessageDialog in terms of visual style, but as the name implies, it's only for collecting credentials from the user.

If this is not what you're looking for, you could check out the guidelines for usage of MessageDialog and the [quickstart guide for MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738364.aspx), both on Microsoft's Dev Center, if you haven't already. I'm sorry I can't provide both the links due to restrictions on new users on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to create your own MessageDialog box: a box that expand on all the screen and which contains user input box.

You can start with the following code: http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2012/03/winjs-a-childwindow-control-to-use-in-your-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Popup class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190.aspx